# Cant create an environment on AWS Cloud 9

Tags: amazon-web-services, ide, environment, cloud9

When i try create an environment on AWS Cloud 9, this happen:

> The environment creation failed with the error: The development environment 'dda98b3b81134eb18121b0fdf83fdc66' failed to create. Delete the 'aws-cloud9-AlgumProjeto-dda98b3b81134eb18121b0fdf83fdc66' stack in AWS CloudFormation, and then try creating the development environment again..

I was only able to create an environment when I made the account, but after closing it and opening another server again, this error appeared above.

Error image: [image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cloud9 service is not available for every region. Please check the region you are creating an environment for. Try using `US East (N. Virginia)us-east-1`.